# When trying to create a DataFrame getting 'TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable' despite calling a series, not a dict?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have created a series from an existing data frame using value_counts(), and want to turn the output of this into a new data frame, as below:

```
yeardata= dataset1['Year'].value_counts()

totals = pd.DataFrame(yeardata)
```

and I am getting the following error:

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

I don't understand this, as nowhere within that code am I trying to call a dict. Using type() for yeardata it confirms that this is a series.

I swear this code was working earlier and I haven't changed anything above it but it's now suddenly kicking out an error

Does anyone know what the issue is?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `to_frame()`:

```
totals = yeardata.to_frame()
```

Comment: thanks! that has worked. Do you know why the original code wasn't working?

Comment: To convert a Series to a dataframe you need to use `to_frame()`. To use pd.DataFrame directly it needs to be a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
totals = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(yeardata)
```

Comment: this throws out error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'from_dict'

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.